# Is $A$ diagonalisable if its unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a

1.$n\times n$ unitary matrix over $\mathbb C$

2.idempotent matrix

such that it is not a diagonal matrix.Is it diagonalisable?

$A$ is idempotent means $A^2=A$ i.e. it satisfies $x^2=x$ i.e $x=0,1$ i.e. minimal polynomial factors into distinct linear factors and hence diagonalisable

$A$ is unitary $ \iff $ $AA^*=I$ where $A^*$ denotes conjugate transpose of $A$ .Now how to find its annihilating polynomial as above?

Comment: If it is unitary, then it is normal, so it is unitarily diagonalizable.

Comment: can you disclose a little bit more what is meant by normal.Why cant I do it from here as I have done in case of idempotent matrix @copper.hat

Comment: Furthermore, unitary matrices are invertible, so from $A^2 = A$, you already can conlude $A = I$.

Comment: what $A^2=A$?? how ?@k.stm

Comment: You're the one who wrote $A^2=A$.  Is that a different matrix from the unitary one?

Comment: No buddy I wrote that for idempotent matrix I am asking for unitary matrix @k.stm

Comment: @learnmore I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2):

For item 1, use [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), $A = U T U^*$ and use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#Consequences):

> **Proposition.** A normal triangular matrix is diagonal.

The proof of this statement is easily done by comparing the elements of $TT^*$ and $T^*T$ row by row.

For item 2, just look at Jordan blocks. Can you make one with the eigenvalue $0$ or $1$ such that it is idempotent. You can help yourself with [formulas for powers of Jordan blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers), which should be quite easy to deduce on your own, since you only need the power 2.

(Hint: no, you can't find such Jordan blocks, unless they are of size $1$, i.e., the matrix must be diagonalizable)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question: see the comments...

Concerning your last question: Let's call $x_{lm}$ the matrix elements of $A$, then your polynomials look like:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_{km}x^*_{lk}=\delta_{lm},
$$
since you get $1$ when you build the scalar product of a vector of $A$ with itself and otherwise the vectors are orthogonal.